# Find the shortest path between two given nodes using positive edge weights

Tags: graph-theory

I would like to obtain the shortest path between the nodes $v'$ and $v''$ using positive edge weights in the graph investigated. More precisely, I don't need for the shortest path between $u'$ and $u''$ if $\{u',u''\} \ne \{v',v''\}$. Is there any effective algorithm for this problem?

Comment: Combine Dijkstra's Algorithm with some extra logic.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot....

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: It would have been appreciated to cite two sentences from Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm): "If we are only interested in a shortest path between vertices source and target, we can terminate the search after line 15 if u = target. Now we can read the shortest path from source to target by reverse iteration:".